# css - <p> tag doesn't go up anymore

Tags: html, css

I put a p tag in a div tag.
I want to make the paragraph go higher, but it doesn't move.
But it does go down.

Here's my code:

```css
.iansoft-os {
left: 30%;
background-color: blue;
width: 130px;
height: 140px;
font-family: Ostrich Sans;
color: white;
}
```

```html
 <div class="iansoft-os">
  <a href="https://ianthepark.weebly.com/iansoft-os"><img src="powerpoint_orig.png" width="80px" height="80px" class="pic1" id="pic" onmouseenter="change3()" onmouseleave="change4()" onclick="alert(You are going to be headed to another website.)"></a>
 <p style="color: white; font-size: 12pt; margin-top: 1%">Iansoft OS 1.2.1/1.2.2</p>
 <p style="color: #00db87; font-size: 11pt; text-align: center;">Free</p>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Margin on the P tags to 0 Pixels

```
p {
    margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This scenario happens across multiple browsers, because they have their own default styles set by the browser.

To avoid this issue, you can "reset" all the CSS cross browser by using [reset.css](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Or if you'd like to keep all your styles consistent across the browser, use 
[normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

Comment: And then you'll be stuck with some other default from reset.css or normalize.css that also confuses you.

Comment: Yes and for this case it's better to use reset.css. These are meant to remove the confusion for cross browser.

Comment: I'm sure there is some well meaning intent, but the unavoidable reality is that someone who didn't understand the defaults browsers have will now not understand the defaults some /additional/ .css file has.

Answer (score 0):

In the <p> that you want to move up, you can set a negative margin. This works across all modern browsers.

For example:

```
<p style="color: white; font-size: 12pt; margin-top: -10px">Iansoft OS 1.2.1/1.2.2</p>
```

Just be aware that this will pull up the <p> below it as well.